# Unable to delete file on a pcloud network drive

Tags: macos

I have a file in the root directory of a network file system (pcloud) that I cannot rename or delete, neither as regular user nor as root (sudo). The file is only visible on the Mac Os system that created it, not when I visit and browse the pcloud drive via pcloud's web interface. I have tried all solutions I could find on the web, to no avail.

I'm running macOs Monterey, version 12.6.

Comment: What's the file name? does it, eg start with ._

Comment: The name of the file is "2022-01-19 19-41-17 M NWD-Door.m4v" (without quotation marks). Finder info says it's 3.8 MB on disk.

Comment: OK, not the name then - you're going to have to tell us "all the solutions" you've tried.

Comment: Obviously I've tried straightforward deleting in Finder and in Terminal (rm ..). I've tried deleing as superuser (sudo). Dito using the mv command. I've tried changing permissions by using "chflags -R nouchg ". I've created an empty file with the same name and copied it into the folder in question.

Comment: Did you try rebooting the Mac ?

Comment: "Did you try rebooting the Mac?" -- yes, rebooted many times. Issue persists.

Comment: pcloud uses a cache on your disk, which is normally in `~/.pcloud/Cache/`. I'm not sure how the files appear there, but it's worth having a look. Ultimately I would completely uninstall the pcloud driver, remove the `~/.pcloud/` folder if the uninstall procedure doesn't, reboot, and reinstall.

Comment: Thanks PierU, see my answer below. Just to add a comment .. simply deleting the contents of the Cache folder didn't solve the problem, I needed to delete the entire .pcloud folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is as follows:

(1) Stop the pcloud application

(2) delete the ~/.pcloud folder

(3) restart the pcloud application

After some internal housekeeping activity by the pcloud application, this deletes the previously indelible rogue file.

Many Thanks to PierU whose comment provided the solution.

So in essence, this was a pcloud application issue, not a macos issue. A big "Thank You!" to everyone who read and contributed to the discussion.

Comment: You can accept your own answer, it's OK with me :). It was just a suggestion from my side, as I was not sure it could work. Just, before auto-accepting your answer, make clearer what have done so that other readers do not need to read the comments.

Comment: Thanks, done. Two days before I am permitted to auto-accept my own answer.